# Combining Multi-table Tableau Hyperfiles?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Looking for an easy way in python (or library/tools) to combine multiple, multi-table hyperfiles into 1 file to upload to Tableau Desktop.

I've been able to accomplish this by converting to csv, and back to hyper but its tedious and inefficient larger scale. Hoping there's a better option out there.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more detail as to the scope you are looking to achieve with this and the purpose, what you have tried so far, any code you have written and how converting to csv then back to hyper accomplished your goal. It will be much easier for people to narrow down suggestions or solutions the more detailed your questions are. Check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking effective questions. This seems like and interesting problem but need more info to formulate a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The API for reading and writing Hyper files is called the Tableau Hyper API https://tableau.github.io/hyper-db/

If you build a multi-table Hyper file, and you want to programmatically publish it to a Tableau Server, you can use the Tableau REST API https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm

If you happen to be using Python for your development, there is a Python package that simplifies using the REST API, https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python